# What is the UNCServer process running on my WIndows 10 Laptop?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, performance, process, unc

I have a Lenovo i5 Laptop. There is always a UNCServer process running. Is there some way to identify what that process is doing? Some details of my laptop (from System info):

- Windows 10 Home Build 19044
- 2Tb hard drive
- 8 Gb ram
- Page File Space 5gb
- Total Physical Mem 7.88Gb
- Availablye Physical Mem 3.70Gb
- Total Virtual Mem 12.9Gb
- Available Virtual Mem 7.16

I have also noticed that Task Manager reports very high (90-100%) disk usage, and response is sluggish. Are these related? The hard drive was replaced not very long ago so should be in good condition. Note that these numbers are after a reboot, with no additional programs runnning. Appreciate your help.

Comment: The usage is probably not related to the UNC Server.  Here is some info [What is UNCServer.exe? Is it safe? Can I remove it?](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-uncserver-exe)

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search reveals that UNCServer.exe is a Lenovo update utility.

I myself check the manufacturers website manually for updates every few months, so I don't rely on these kind of tools.

You can uninstall it to save resources.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more detailed answer with references for future readers:

The UNC Server is part of the Lenovo System Update application.

> **UNC** is an abbreviation of the **Universal Naming Convention** and is present on your Lenovo computer to check for updates. (https://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-uncserver-exe)

The `UNCServer.exe` and `tvsu.exe` (Lenovo System Update) files should be located in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\System Update`

If you're uncomfortable about the **Lenovo System Update** software, you can try running an anti-virus scan and if it's undesired on your system, you can even safely uninstall it.

Additional details and uninstall instructions here: https://www.partitionwizard.com/clone-disk/uncserver.html

Comment: Regarding high disk usage, my personal opinion is that this Lenovo application is probably unoptimized and could be the culprit, but it's also likely to be some other background process.